# How can I compare values to each other in two different pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different pandas data frames.  One is called 'price' and it has the schema

```
SKU, price
```

The second data frame is called sales_tracking which contains information about the number of sales for a SKU at a given price.  It's schema is

```
SKU, price, total_orders, total_visits
```

But when we add a new price point for a SKU in the 'price' data frame, there won't be a matching record in the 'sales_tracking' data frame, at which point I have to add a new entry to the 'sales_tracking' data frame where the total_orders and total_visits is estimated from another data set (we're doing this to estimate conversion rates).

The problem I'm having is being able to check to see if the value for price in the pricing data frame also exists in the sales_tracking data frame. Before doing the comparison, I first create temporary data frames for both the pricing data and the sales data as follows:

```
sku_specific_sales_records = sales_tracking[sales_tracking['product']==product]

sku_specific_price = sku_specific_price [sku_specific_price ['product']==product]
```

To be clear, both sku_specific_sales_records and sku_specific_price may contain multiple record.  I'm trying to identify the case when there is a row in sku_specific_price where sku_specific_price['price'] is not in sku_specific_sales_records['price'].

I have tried various different things. Something as simple as

```
if sku_specific_sales_records['price'] == sku_specific_price['price']:
```

doesn't work, I get a ValueError "can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'.  So I also tried

```
if sku_specific_price['price'].isin(sku_specific_sales_records['price']):
   doTheThingIfTheyMatch
else:
   doTheOtherThing
```

And that generates a different ValueError: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). So I tried using a.bool()

```
if sku_specific_price['price'].isin(sku_specific_sales_records['price']).bool():
   doTheThingIfTheyMatch
else:
   doTheOtherThing
```

but that brought me back full circle to the "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects".

Here is a small example illustrating the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
sales = pd.DataFrame(columns={'product', 'price', 'sales', 'orders'})
pricing = pd.DataFrame(columns={'product', 'price'})
sales.loc[0] = [123, 10, 5, 5]
sales.loc[1] = [123, 15, 2, 10]
pricing.loc[0] = [123, 8]
if sales['price'].isin(pricing['price']):
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Uh, too much text. Please provide a [mcve] with some small data samples in your question instead. Thanks.

Comment: @Parfait I was unaware.  I spend half my time in Irvine CA, and Seattle WA.  I'm in Irvine now.  I'm reading your link tho to see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution seems to be to replace .bool() with .any() as follows

```
import pandas as pd
sales = pd.DataFrame(columns={'product', 'price', 'sales', 'orders'})
pricing = pd.DataFrame(columns={'product', 'price'})
sales.loc[0] = [123, 10, 5, 5]
sales.loc[1] = [123, 15, 2, 10]
pricing.loc[0] = [123, 8]
if sales['price'].isin(sales['price']).any() 
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

.bool() didn't work because .bool() only works on single elements, i.e. scalar values.  I was trying to use it check if the values in one series were in another series, so even though my sales data frame only contained a single row, it was possible for the sales data frame to contain multiple rows.  The .any() or .all() defines what conditions must be met for the comparison to be true.

For example, I want to find out if we have any rows in pricing for a particular SKU that don't exist in sales (e.g. a new pricing point), in that case I would use
    import pandas as pd
    sales.loc[0] = [123, 10, 5, 5]
    sales.loc[1] = [123, 15, 2, 10]
    pricing.loc[0] = [123, 8]
    pricing.loc[1] = [123, 10]
    pricing.loc[2] = [123, 15]
    print sales
    print pricing
    print sales['price']
    print pricing['price']
    if pricing['price'].isin(sales['price']).all():
        print "true"
    else:
        print "false"

because I need all of the values in pricing['price'] to be matched to sales['price'].  If I only required a single matching value, then I'd use .any().

Answer (score 0):

In `python`, you need to use `==` instead of `=` when evaluating comparisons.

This is because `=` is the assignment operator, so it cannot be used for comparisons.

Try this:

```
if sku_specific_sales_records['price'] == sku_specific_price['price']:
```

Note: It's also recommended to use short(er) variable names as there's less chance for typos and they're quicker to type.

Comment: Hey Adi219,
Thanks, those are actually typos.  In the original code I have ==.  I'll go back and edit those in addition to posting a MVC example.